# Display marker on top of other markers on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am looking for javascript code that display marker on top of others.
May be there is any method of **GMarker** that set marker on top (z-index kind of).

For solution, I destroy marker and created again. The solution works before some time (when I tried this solution) but not right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a parameter zIndexProcess.

```
var marker = new GMarker( latlng, { zIndexProcess: "your z index for marker"  } );
```

Should work.

Check this link as well.

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/zindex.htm